x2go client: error in the connection load module (PATH)
I am using x2go in my servers, and it is working perfectly and is very fast.
But in some servers that some modules are loaded in login time in this path /etc/profile.d/Mymodules.sh there is a problem. In this file, I have this line: module load myenv When I comment this line, everything is fine. But when it is not commented, x2go cannot connect to the server.
When I want to connect to the server, it shows me this error and disconnect from the server:
Error in the connection load myenv (PATH)

Client and servers are Ubuntu 20.04 with XFCE desktop environment.
Any clue to solve this?

I have found these solutions for my servers. It is recommended to hide the output of the module command in your script.

There are two solutions for Ubuntu:

1- The stdout and stderr are redirected to /dev/null
module load myenv > /dev/null 2>&1
2- Use builtin option of module command to silent the errors,warnings and information.
module load myenv --silent

For Rocky linux use below command:

exec 2>/dev/null
module load alias_licenses
exec 2>/dev/tty

